# Why choose Lisp for a project?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp

I am seeking concrete and unique features that Lisp (any dialect) offers to a project, compared to the other primarily functional languages.

For example, Haskell offers lazy-evaluation, purity and a type-system which helps build more correct programs. Erlang makes concurrent programming easier by using message passing exclusively, lightweight processes, and so on.

What does LISP bring to the table? What makes it a better suite than other languages for certain projects? What are its features that the other languages lack to make it suitable?

I am not bashing at Lisp; I want to learn more about it and what advantages it offers if used today. Please be specific :)

Comment: I think this would be better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com if it would be accompanied by some concrete project description.

Comment: Yes, I did realize this is better off at programmers.stackexchange.com just after I posted :) Flagged the question and hope some moderator will move it soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I asked my self questions similar to yours, I searched and found this article:

- http://www.defmacro.org/ramblings/lisp.html

It doesn't go too much into details, but gives a coarse picture of why Lisp makes sense. I found it very useful (and the whole http://www.defmacro.org/ site for that matter - like the posts there a lot, e.g. [this one](http://www.defmacro.org/ramblings/fp.html)).

Comment: The link is definitely interesting but I feel it doesn't really answer my question.. It presents advantages of functional programming which are possible in other languages (for ex. Haskell is especially advertised for DSL). My question is what does Lisp bring new inside the functional paradigm? The killer feature(s) which makes you want to write your project in a dialect of Lisp because you can't find it in other langueges..

Comment: Well, that's the point - in my opinion, it doesn't. Sections `Hello Lisp!` and `Lisp Macros` I think say this the best. What Lisp has is - code = data, which enables macros, which enables you to tailor Lisp to your needs. That's unique to Lisp - it gives you freedom to mold it however you with. It's also very succinct - especially Clojure, you have a lot of ways to make the code that's a lot shorter than in other languages. Note also Lisp is not functional by default (compared to e.g. Haskell), you can happily use it imperatively, for example.

Comment: Also see this: http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html.

Comment: You are right about the macros, they are very powerful especially since the macro language is Lisp itself. Is this macro mechanism the biggest feature Lisp offers which other functional languages do not?

Comment: I'd say not - it is definitively very important, but the foundation that even macros depend is code = data idea. E.g. in Clojure, when you say `(let [a 1] (inc a))`, this is a quite standard `let` **code** block. On the other hand, you can readily change this using a macro without any special language syntax - that code block becomes **data** block readily and without any change.

Comment: To summarize (and speaking about Clojure again), I'd say in order of importance is: 1) code = data, 2) macros, 3) dynamic (no static-typing noise and no compilation - speeds up development considerably), 4) succinct (e.g. anonymous functions, direct reader support for lists, maps, sets, regexps), 5) support for FP (e.g. higher-order functions) and easy testing

Comment: Sure thing Adi, glad to help! Do search around the Net, though, you'll find plenty of resources to form a more complete picture and see whether it's something you want to use or not. Right tool for the job...

Comment: Just a correction about the no compilation comment: Common Lisp has optional compilation of each function or method -- the best of both worlds.

Comment: @John Clojure and other lisps (e.g. elisp) have compilation, too, however I think this is more a nuisance for development then help. While it's good to have compiler warn you about issues, I find tests cover this much better. YMMV, of course.

Comment: Compilation is good for performance. I agree it often doesn't help during development.

Comment: @Adi, it is not about functional programming. Actually, you can define a Lisp dialect with no support for FP at all, purely imperative, but still with most of the Lisp advantages. Lisp is different because of two things: homoiconicity and macros. All the rest could vary, but these two things are defining.

Comment: @SK-logic Thank you, now I'm starting to understand

Answer (score 1):

> Haskell offers lazy evaluation

Clojure sequence functions are lazy. You can work with infinite lists just like in haskell:

```
(take 10 (cycle ["odd" "even"]))
```

> purity

Clojure types are immutable. That makes large parts of your program pure without forcing you to climb the ivory tower :) Plus it has STM, just like haskell.

> and a type-system

Unfortunately here lisps cannot compete with haskell. Mosts lisps are dynamic.

But dynamic nature of lisps and their VM (image) makes them an awesome choice for a server side programs, like web applications. It is very easy to connect to a running instance of your web app, and change functions or even entire modules on the fly, without restarting application or kicking out users. That is either not possible or very cumbersome with haskell.

Most lisps provide a very easy way to write macros. You write macros in the same language.

With Haskell you will have to learn yet another language (Template Haskell) which is much more complicated and to this day is not even properly documented. You will have a hard time learning it.

Having said that, i use and love both lisp (clojure) and haskell. I prefer haskell because it has the most powerful type system of any available for practical development language.

Plus it bends your mind better than mushrooms :)

Comment: I really like your response :) Thank you! But I still can't see a  killer feature for Lisp, even for a web app, to make you write the project in it. Erlang, for example, was designed specifically to support hot swappable code, 100% uptime, etc :) This makes it really good to write back-ends for webapps in it..

Answer (score 0):

Scheme provides [hygenic macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygienic_macro) and [continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation).  I'm not sure what other fp languages also provide these features.

Comment: Some ML dialects provide continutations too. And hygienic macros are inferior to the common lisp-style, pure macros. Hygienic macros are as powerful as C++ templates (and no more than that), which is pathetic.

Comment: @SK-logic `syntax-rules` is less powerful than `defmacro`.  `syntax-case`, however, is strictly more powerful than `defmacro` (in that you can easily implement ANSI CL's `defmacro` in terms of `syntax-case`, but not vice versa).

Comment: @Matthias Benkard, since you can circumvent the hygiene with `syntax-case` (which only appeared officialy in R6RS), it is not a hygienic macro system. A purely hygienic macro system will always be less flexible. Btw, you can also implement `syntax-case` on top of `defmacro`, so it is not "more powerful".

Comment: @SK-logic IMHO, an impure hygienic macro system (`syntax-case`, Explicit Renaming, Syntactic Closures, etc.) is still a hygienic macro system, just as an impure functional language is still a functional language; but this is just definition nitpicking either way.  Anyway, I don't believe you can implement `syntax-case` using ANSI CL `defmacro` only.  You can do it if you have sufficient access to the lexical environment, but that is non-ANSI, and I am not aware of even a semi-portable compatibility library that provides enough of it so as to make an implementation of `syntax-case` feasible.

Comment: @Matthias Benkard, I implemented `syntax-case` using the trivial macros only, but I had to build a whole new macro expander and half of the compiler on top - i.e., each top-level expression is expanded down to the core forms, and lexical environment is passed to each inner macro.

Comment: @SK-logic Ah, I see.  That's true, if you replace the macro expander, it's possible.  I'm guessing that in order to use it, you have to wrap everything in some kind of `with-syntax-case-macros` macro or, alternatively, use a custom `compile` function?  (That's quite okay, I guess, for what it provides. :))

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7761/discussion-between-matthias-benkard-and-sk-logic)